# Java PreparedStatement doesn´t set value

Tags: java, sql-server, prepared-statement

I´m totally new to Java and I try to set up a little test to read some data from a MSSQL-database. I have to pass some values to the query but that does not work properly, if I set them manually it works, in my case with the PreparedStatement and the .setLong-Method it does not work.

```
public class db_testClass {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

    long firstId = 0;
    long lastId = 201801001010010403L;
    PreparedStatement statement;
    int counter = 1;

     String SQL = "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpDaten') IS NOT NULL
                "            DROP TABLE #tmpDaten;  
                "        SELECT  DISTINCT 
                "                RIGHT(10000000 + ISNULL(r.xxx, 0), 7) AS Wert
                "        INTO    #tmpDaten 
                "        FROM    dbo.xxx  
                "        WHERE   r.xxxx BETWEEN firstId = ? AND lastId = ?; 

                "        SELECT DISTINCT 
                "                'xxxx' AS Art ,
                "                t.xxx 
                "        FROM    #tmpDaten 
                "                LEFT JOIN xxxxxxx a ON a.xxxx = t.xxxx 
                "                AND a.ART =   'xxxx'                                     " + 
                "        WHERE   a.xxxx IS NULL;";


    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxxx:1433;databaseName=xxxxxx;integratedSecurity=true;";
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

    try {

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl); 
            statement = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
            statement.setLong(1, firstId);
            statement.setLong(2, lastId);
            System.out.println(statement);
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();


    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

The error says that there is wrong syntax nearby the '='......

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks,

Daniel

Comment: When you say, "doesn't work", what do you mean? You get an error? If so, please include it in your question. If not, please explain what doesn't work.

Comment: A `DROP TABLE` command cannot be called from `executeQuery()`, which is only for select statements.  Also, you should probably break up your query into separate pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of the `BETWEEN` operator is suspicious and probably just an outright syntax violation.  It should be something like:

```
something BETWEEN low-value AND high-value
```

to test if the *something* lies between the values *low-value* and *hi-value*.

Comment: I finally got it with replacing the "firstId = ?" just with a "?" and it works, thanks!

Comment: I suspected that might be the solution.  Glad to be of assistance.

Comment: @dd9176 I have the same issue seems that I don't have any parameters in the query and it's crashes. https://stackoverflow.com/q/78015586/586439