# Error when trying to set PreparedStatement parameters

Tags: java, apache-calcite, apache-arrow-flight

This is the dependency I'm testing with.

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.arrow</groupId>
   <artifactId>flight-sql-jdbc-driver</artifactId>
   <version>13.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
public static void handleSqlStatements() throws SQLException {
    String url = "jdbc:arrow-flight://localhost:5000;useEncryption=false;";
    var connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    String sql = "select * from SometypeDB.`Table` where OID = ?"; 
    System.out.println("SQL query: " + sql); 
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
         PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        int parameterIndex = 1; 
        long value = 123L;

        System.out.println("Setting parameter at index " + parameterIndex + " to value " + value);
        statement.setLong(parameterIndex, value);
        System.out.println("Executing SQL query: " + sql);

        try (ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) {
            
        }// Process ResultSet
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // Ensure detailed error output is available
    }
}
```

This is the error I get when I'm running the code:

```
SQL query: select * from SometypeDB.`Table` where OID = ?
Setting parameter at index 1 to value 123
java.sql.SQLException: parameter ordinal 1 out of range
    at cfjd.org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:60)
    at cfjd.org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaPreparedStatement.getParameter(AvaticaPreparedStatement.java:427)
    at cfjd.org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaPreparedStatement.getSite(AvaticaPreparedStatement.java:434)
    at cfjd.org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaPreparedStatement.setLong(AvaticaPreparedStatement.java:178)
```

Adding the part in the code that throws the exception:

```
protected AvaticaParameter getParameter(int param) throws SQLException {
        try {
            return (AvaticaParameter)this.getSignature().parameters.get(param - 1);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException var3) {
            throw AvaticaConnection.HELPER.toSQLException(AvaticaConnection.HELPER.createException("parameter ordinal " + param + " out of range"));
        }
    }`
```

Comment: Does this query work fine when the value is hardcoded?

Comment: Have you tried using `setInt` instead? Some JDBC drivers do not properly implement the JDBC requirements to transparently convert between compatible types. On the other hand, the error suggests that it doesn't recognize there is a parameter 1...

Comment: @chameerar no sir, that doesn't work

Comment: @MarkRotteveel correct seems that's on for a flight-jdbc with a duckdb and other vector db's happening. I was hoping to see someone solving this one. :(

Comment: I wonder why this time I got -1? I think I gave the whole information and explained everything. @MarkRotteveel

Comment: Maybe an incorrect driver implementation? Try a parameter index of zero

Comment: @g00se by a default it's 1 base index and I see from the concrete implementation it's throws an exception

Comment: Why are you getting the connection twice, and leaking one of them?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by the bit about the "concrete implementation". Why the backticks? That's usually a MySql thing. Try dropping them

Comment: It's not mysql , it's our company implementation of VDB

Comment: So it’s a bug in your company’s JDBC driver.

Comment: @user207421 I guess it's an implementation of the result-schema, seems like an issue in our implementation.

Comment: I don't know how you reach that conclusion. Looks more like an SQL parsing bug to me.

Comment: From what I understand it's relate to metadata that is returned by the sql provider which is pointing to the source of the problem, which is the vdb that we are not returning this metadata. This is by jdbc developer.